# Was it Daniel who sealed the book in Daniel 12?

Tags: daniel

Daniel 12:4 NASB

> [4]But as for you, Daniel, conceal these words and seal up the book until the end of time; many will go back and forth, and knowledge will increase."

But in verse 9 it says

> Daniel 12:9 NASB
>
> [9]He said, "Go your way, Daniel, for these words are concealed and sealed up until the end time.

In verse 4 it seems like Daniel sealed the book but in verse 9 the narrative changes, So was it Daniel or somebody else who sealed the book?

Comment: As it stands in English, I understand verse 4 to be an instruction FOR DANIEL to conceal the words and seal the book. I'll have a look at the Hebrew.

Comment: Couldn't verse 8 mean that Daniel did it, and verse 9 mean that 'these _having been sealed up,_ go your way'?

Comment: Why does the "narrative change"? 12:4 Daniel told to seal; 12:9, the words are sealed. Cf. [Daniel 8:26](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Daniel+8%3A26&version=NIV). Not a problem, as far as I can see.

Comment: @Dɑvïd, is it God or Daniel who seals the book. my problem is how Daniel could make the book not to be understood, revealed when it took the lamb who was worthy to unseal it

Comment: There's no "lamb" in Dan 12. Did you read Dan 8:26? See also, for comparison, [Isaiah 8:16](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Isaiah+8%3A16&version=NIV). What makes you think the scroll of Rev 5:5 is Daniel's scroll? And if Revelation 5 is your problem for Daniel 12, why didn't you say so in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Daniel followed God's instructions to "seal" or shut up the scroll.  That meant that Daniel was not to tell the people what had been shown to him as the time was not yet right.  It was still 490 years into their future.

But, in verse 9 the sealing was done by God's instruction and command, and therefore was God's doing.  Then, the ultimate responsibility remained with God.